# Can't seem to find the right timing for the slide animation, <divs> overlapping?

Tags: html, css, animation, slide, keyframe

First, I wasn't entirely sure what to look for because I'm extremely new to CSS and apologies for explaining poorly. But any help or correction on what I did or needed to do would be much appreciated.

I have a simple CSS slide show animation but can't seem to get the timings right or the right keyframes. Instead, I get divs overlapping one another. I could probably get better results using Javascript or Jquery but I wanted to know if my goal could be accomplished just by using animation in CSS.

I have the parent (.container) with 5 child (4  and a ) inside that parent (.container). My goal was to have them slide to be viewed one by one at least for 50sec each child before sliding to the next (the next div/footer) while others not in view be hidden.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .box1 {
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
      }

      .box2 {
        background: green;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
      }

      .box3 {
        background: blue;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
      }

      .box4 {
        background: orange;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
      }

      footer {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 100px;
        background: black;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px 0 0 0;
      }

      .container {
        border: 5px solid yellow;
        height: 18em;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .container>* {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        animation: 50s autoplay infinite ease-in-out;
      }

      @keyframes autoplay {
        0% {
          top: 100%;
        }

        20% {
          top: 0%;
        }

        33.33% {
          top: 0%;
        }

        37.33% {
          top: -100%;
        }

        100% {
          top: -100%;
        }
      }

      .container>*:nth-child(1) {
        animation-delay: 0s;
      }

      .container>*:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: 10s;
      }

      .container>*:nth-child(3) {
        animation-delay: 20s;
      }

      .container>*:nth-child(4) {
        animation-delay: 30s;
      }

      .container>*:nth-child(5) {
        animation-delay: 40s;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Auto Slide Animation</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box1">
        <h3>So What is This About?</h3>
        <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam nec eros in neque aliquam efficitur. Duis pulvinar efficitur iaculis. Fusce luctus ac dolor ac tincidunt. Sed porta a sapien vitae volutpat. Fusce elementum enim sit amet sodales consequat. Curabitur eget nisl lacus. Mauris vitae eleifend nisl. Sed commodo massa ac ex bibendum, ornare vehicula lectus maximus. Suspendisse vitae imperdiet tortor.</p>
        <p>Aenean posuere quam turpis, ut convallis erat egestas sed. Morbi blandit diam at orci tincidunt, quis vehicula ipsum dapibus. Nunc ut dolor metus. Phasellus ullamcorper ex mi, nec euismod elit hendrerit sit amet. Mauris elementum vitae felis sed blandit. Phasellus sed hendrerit nisi. Morbi eu leo porta leo vehicula fermentum ut nec dolor. Aenean porta bibendum turpis nec fringilla. Donec non accumsan mi. Etiam egestas urna a sollicitudin sagittis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <h3>Participation</h3>
        <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam nec eros in neque aliquam efficitur. Duis pulvinar efficitur iaculis. Fusce luctus ac dolor ac tincidunt. Sed porta a sapien vitae volutpat. Fusce elementum enim sit amet sodales consequat. Curabitur eget nisl lacus. Mauris vitae eleifend nisl. Sed commodo massa ac ex bibendum, ornare vehicula lectus maximus. Suspendisse vitae imperdiet tortor.</p>
        <p>Aenean posuere quam turpis, ut convallis erat egestas sed. Morbi blandit diam at orci tincidunt, quis vehicula ipsum dapibus. Nunc ut dolor metus. Phasellus ullamcorper ex mi, nec euismod elit hendrerit sit amet. Mauris elementum vitae felis sed blandit. Phasellus sed hendrerit nisi. Morbi eu leo porta leo vehicula fermentum ut nec dolor. Aenean porta bibendum turpis nec fringilla. Donec non accumsan mi. Etiam egestas urna a sollicitudin sagittis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box3">
        <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam nec eros in neque aliquam efficitur. Duis pulvinar efficitur iaculis. Fusce luctus ac dolor ac tincidunt. Sed porta a sapien vitae volutpat. Fusce elementum enim sit amet sodales consequat. Curabitur eget nisl lacus. Mauris vitae eleifend nisl. Sed commodo massa ac ex bibendum, ornare vehicula lectus maximus. Suspendisse vitae imperdiet tortor.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box4">
        <h3>Requirements</h3>
        <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam nec eros in neque aliquam efficitur. Duis pulvinar efficitur iaculis. Fusce luctus ac dolor ac tincidunt. Sed porta a sapien vitae volutpat. Fusce elementum enim sit amet sodales consequat. Curabitur eget nisl lacus. Mauris vitae eleifend nisl. Sed commodo massa ac ex bibendum, ornare vehicula lectus maximus. Suspendisse vitae imperdiet tortor.</p>
        <p>Aenean posuere quam turpis, ut convallis erat egestas sed. Morbi blandit diam at orci tincidunt, quis vehicula ipsum dapibus. Nunc ut dolor metus. Phasellus ullamcorper ex mi, nec euismod elit hendrerit sit amet. Mauris elementum vitae felis sed blandit. Phasellus sed hendrerit nisi. Morbi eu leo porta leo vehicula fermentum ut nec dolor. Aenean porta bibendum turpis nec fringilla. Donec non accumsan mi. Etiam egestas urna a sollicitudin sagittis.</p>
        <p>Aenean posuere quam turpis, ut convallis erat egestas sed. Morbi blandit diam at orci tincidunt, quis vehicula ipsum dapibus. Nunc ut dolor metus. Phasellus ullamcorper ex mi, nec euismod elit hendrerit sit amet. Mauris elementum vitae felis sed blandit.</p>
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include a reproducible example of your issue. There isn't much we can do with only CSS. Perhaps a snippet?

Comment: Are you animating the footer too? If you are animating 4 items you need to pause each at top 0 for 25% of the time. If you are animating 5 items then you need to pause each for 20% of the time.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I believe for the result you need it is better to add the logical structure of Javascript code or Jquery code. You have the usage logic to build the script with setTimeout and add the logic you want.Something like that, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: Thanks for this! But I really just needed it in CSS using animation.